# Let's get rid of [apdu-command]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There is no real difference between [apdu-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apdu-command) and [apdu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apdu). They both refer to the same smart card communication protocol. The second one has some followers and tagged questions. The first one does not.

Let's get rid of [apdu-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apdu-command).